# IdCookieManager cut part of server cookie which contains quotechar

Tags: http, delphi, cookies, indy

There's a problem with IdCookieManager. When server returns cookie where value contains `"`, it recognize first occurrence of `"` as end of value. You can reproduce it easily with next code:

```pascal
procedure TSomeObject.Test;
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Cookie: TIdCookieManager;
  i: Integer;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  Cookie := TIdCookieManager.Create(HTTP);
  HTTP.CookieManager := Cookie;
  HTTP.HandleRedirects := True;

  HTTP.Get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set?test_cookie1=' +
    TIdURI.ParamsEncode('{"key": 123}') + '&test_cookie2=&test_cookie3=value');

  for i := 0 to Cookie.CookieCollection.Count - 1 do
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(Cookie.CookieCollection[i].CookieName + ' = ' +
      Cookie.CookieCollection[i].Value);

  HTTP.Free;
end;
```

Digging into Indy sources I found that problem is in `TIdCookie.ParseServerCookie()`. It uses `IdGlobal.Fetch()` to extract value between quotes and ... it does what it does.

Would you recommend me how to let it parse whole value?

Comment: Per the [official cookie spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265), there are no special provisions for escaping `"` characters inside of a quoted string. In fact, the `"` character is NOT allowed to appear AT ALL inside of a quoted string. So your test is faulty to begin with!

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I could stay with official cookie spec, but I've used request to httpbin just for example. There're at least 2 websites with dozens of millions visitors daily which don't care about any standarts and use escaped quote in cookie, so I have to handle it somehow.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question to include real-world examples, as well as analysis of how browsers are actually handling these malformed cookies back and forth.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, for privacy reasons I can't include "real-world" example, but you can be sure that I've reproduced it properly. Real browsers handle it perfectly (you can open [this](http://httpbin.org/cookies/set?test_cookie1={%22key%22:%20123}&test_cookie2=&test_cookie3=value) link in browser with developer tools and check that cookies parsed properly). Also python's `requests` handle it without any issues.

Comment: When I see how FireFox stores the 3 cookies of your example, the server-reported cookie `Set-Cookie: test_cookie1="{\"key\": 123}"; Path=/` is stored as `"{\"key\": 123}"` not as `{"key": 123}`, so the quoted string is not being parsed at all. I also added a 4th test cookie `...&test_cookie4=test%3B` and the server reported the cookie as `Set-Cookie: test_cookie4="test\073"; Path=/` which FireFox stored as `"test\073"` instead of `test;` So 1), the server is translating the input params oddly, and 2), FireFox is not parsing quoted strings. ```\``` escaping applies to JSON, not to cookies.

Comment: Re-reading RFC 6265, I now believe the quote characters in a quoted string are actually part of the cookie value data, and so Indy should not be trying to strip them off the quotes at all.  So I will look into fixing that.

Comment: I have now updated `TIdCookie.ParseServerCookie()` to no longer remove surrounding quotes from cookie values

Comment: @RemyLebeau, You're right and that's correct way. It have to be stored as `"{\"key\": 123}"`. Thank you for your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no neat solution *(at least I haven't found one)* ,so I've added `OnHeadersAvailable` event listener to `TIdHTTP` which rewrites cookie value after `TIdCookie.ParseServerCookie()` executed and replace previously parsed cookies by adding new cookie with same name to `TIdCookieManager`.

Code **(DO NOT USE THIS HANDLER, THERE'S ONE MORE BELOW)**:

```pascal
procedure TSomeObject.FixCookies(Sender: TObject; AHeaders: TIdHeaderList;
var VContinue: Boolean);
const
  CookieDelimiter = ';';
  QuoteChar = '"';
  SpaceChar = ' ';
var
  RawHeader, RawCookie, RawCookieValue: string;
  i, CookieDelimiterPos, CookieNamePos, CookieValuePos: Integer;
  Cookie: TIdCookie;
begin
  for i := 0 to AHeaders.Count - 1 do
  begin
    RawHeader := AHeaders[i];
    if Pos('Set-Cookie', RawHeader) = 1 then  // starts with "Set-Cookie"
    begin
      for CookieNamePos := Length('Set-Cookie') + 2 to Length(RawHeader) do
        if RawHeader[CookieNamePos] <> SpaceChar then
          Break;

      RawCookie := Copy(RawHeader, CookieNamePos,
        Length(RawHeader) - CookieNamePos + 1);
      CookieDelimiterPos := Pos(CookieDelimiter, RawCookie);
      CookieValuePos := Pos('=', RawCookie);

      if (CookieDelimiterPos > 0) and (CookieValuePos > 0) then
      begin
        RawCookieValue := Copy(RawCookie, CookieValuePos + 1,
          CookieDelimiterPos - CookieValuePos - 1);
        if (Length(RawCookieValue) > 0) and (RawCookieValue[1] = QuoteChar) and
          (RawCookieValue[Length(RawCookieValue)] = QuoteChar) then
          RawCookieValue := Copy(RawCookieValue, 2, Length(RawCookieValue) - 2);

        with (Sender as TIdHTTP) do
        begin
          Cookie := TIdCookie.Create(nil);
          if Cookie.ParseServerCookie(RawCookie, URL) then
          begin
            Cookie.Value := RawCookieValue;
            CookieManager.CookieCollection.AddCookie(Cookie, URL);
          end
          else
            Cookie.Free;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  VContinue := True;
end;
```

Usage:

```pascal
HTTP.OnHeadersAvailable := FixCookies; // Set it after object initialization
```

**P.S.** I haven't used delphi for long time, so I'm sure that code isn't perfect and lot of improvements could be done *(welcome to comments)*, but **it works**.

---

I have no clue how it happened but using this event handler somehow brakes `TIdCookieManager` and `Cookie.CookieCollection.Count` returns `0` while there're cookies in collection which successfully added in further requests..

I have no mood to spend more time digging into Indy sources so I changed handler to modify existing cookies instead of replacing them. It doesn't brake anything *(probably)*:

```pascal
procedure TSomeObject.FixCookies(Sender: TObject; AHeaders: TIdHeaderList;
  var VContinue: Boolean);
const
  CookieDelimiter = ';';
  QuoteChar = '"';
  SpaceChar = ' ';
var
  RawHeader, RawCookie, RawCookieValue, RawCookieName: string;
  i, CookieDelimiterPos, CookieNamePos, CookieValuePos, CookieIndex: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to AHeaders.Count - 1 do
  begin
    RawHeader := AHeaders[i];
    if Pos('Set-Cookie', RawHeader) = 1 then  // starts with "Set-Cookie"
    begin
      for CookieNamePos := Length('Set-Cookie') + 2 to Length(RawHeader) do
        if RawHeader[CookieNamePos] <> SpaceChar then
          Break;

      RawCookie := Copy(RawHeader, CookieNamePos,
        Length(RawHeader) - CookieNamePos + 1);
      CookieDelimiterPos := Pos(CookieDelimiter, RawCookie);
      CookieValuePos := Pos('=', RawCookie);

      if (CookieDelimiterPos > 0) and (CookieValuePos > 0) then
      begin
        RawCookieName := Copy(RawCookie, 1, CookieValuePos - 1);
        RawCookieValue := Copy(RawCookie, CookieValuePos + 1,
          CookieDelimiterPos - CookieValuePos - 1);
        if (Length(RawCookieValue) > 0) and (RawCookieValue[1] = QuoteChar) and
          (RawCookieValue[Length(RawCookieValue)] = QuoteChar) then
          RawCookieValue := Copy(RawCookieValue, 2, Length(RawCookieValue) - 2);

        with (Sender as TIdHTTP) do
        begin
          CookieIndex := CookieManager.CookieCollection.GetCookieIndex
            (RawCookieName);
          if CookieIndex >= 0 then
            CookieManager.CookieCollection[CookieIndex].Value := RawCookieValue
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  VContinue := True;
end;
```

**P.S.** Are there any Indy developers? I just a bit confused how does first handler let CookieCollection to return zero.

Comment: "*Are there any Indy developers?*" - yes, me. And you should have posted this issue to Indy's [issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues), where it can be tracked properly. A *proper* solution would be to update `ParseServerCookie()` to recognized escaped `"` characters - which BTW, the [official cookie spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265) does not make any special provisions for, which is why `ParseServerCookie()` doesn't currently handle them. The `"` character is NOT allowed to appear inside of a quoted string at all, so your test is faulty to begin with!

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, I'll post it a bit later. The question to developer was "how does first handler brake CookieCollection", it's what confused me. I have list of issues which I will post to issue tracker, especially connected to CookieManager.

Comment: I don't have time right now to analyze your code to figure out why it is breaking the CookieManager.  You wrote the code, you should figure it out.  It will be a good exercise in practicing your debugging skills.